# Dynamic bidirectional RNN Type error

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to execute the following piece of code:

```
# GRU Network
# Forward cell
cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(num_units=n_hidden, activation='tanh')
# Backward cell
cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(num_units=n_hidden, activation='tanh')

GRUOutput, _, _ = tf.contrib.rnn.stack_bidirectional_dynamic_rnn([cell_fw], [cell_bw], inputs, dtype=tf.float32) # <-- Error Here!
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

inputs has size [32, 200, 50], and n_hidden = 50.

Could someone please tell me where I'm going wrong? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass string object as activation function, while it must be a callable (`tf.nn.relu` for instance).

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I used the example given in the documentation, where the default activation was 'tanh'.